# Need Help in Htaccess rewtitig rule for Get variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a beginner in development. I am using htaccess file to rewrite my url. I took help from many websites including Stackoverflow for this purpose. I wrote my own reiterate rule but failed.

My URL is : *www.example.com/post.php?url=abc*

I am trying to get this URL: *www.example.com/abc*

for that i am writing following URL rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) post.php?url=$1 [L]
```

this didn't work so I wrote following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/ post.php?url=$`enter code here`1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This is also not working
Please suggest

Comment: try something like this  RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+)/?$    post.php?url=$1    [NC,L]

Comment: your ?url=abc would be static or dynamic ?

Comment: I tried RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ post.php?url=$1 [NC,L] Its also not working.and yes url is dynamic.